# Require help understanding Flask url_for()

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I am currently testing the `login()` route but have trouble with the redirect.
I would like to be redirected to the main index page.

My authentication blueprint looks like this:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

mod = Blueprint('auth', __name__, url_prefix='/auth')


@mod.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect(url_for('general.index'))
    return render_template('auth/login.html')

@mod.route('/logout', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def logout():
    # Delete session token
    return render_template('auth/logout.html')

@mod.route('/tokeninfo')
def token_info():
    return render_template('auth/tokeninfo.html')
```

Additionally, my `general` blueprint is defined as:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

mod = Blueprint('general', __name__)


@mod.route('/')
@mod.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('general/index.html')
```

However, every time I submit the form on the `/login` route I get redirected to `localhost:5000/auth` and receive a `404 page not found error`.

I have tried adjusting the `return redirect(url_for('general.index'))` in the following ways, but none was successful:

- `return redirect(url_for(general.index))`
- `return redirect(url_for('general.index'))`
- `return redirect(url_for('../general.index'))`

EDIT:

It seems that submitting the login form is only a POST on /auth, and not on /auth/login. This is what appears on the server log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2017 15:06:59] "GET /auth/login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2017 15:07:03] "POST /auth HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

What am I missing / not understanding?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the template!

In my login template, I previously had:

```
<form action="/auth" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
```

However, since I am transitioning to a blueprint powered app, I needed the following change:

```
<form action="/auth/login" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
```

Now the redirect is working as expected.